# Can't see other computers in the network when I am on 5Ghz

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, peer-to-peer

I have a strange issue. I am using Windows 11 home on one computer and Windows 8.1 on the other. They are both on Wifi. If I connect both on the 5Ghz network I can't see the other computer or for that matter any computer on the network, I can't share files etc.

If either of the computers switches to the 2.4Ghz then I can see, share etc. Didn't know Windows 11 had such quirks

Comment: I have 4 computers on laptop mix of 2.4 and 5 GHz (Windows 11 and 10) and share files without issue.   Did you check Public/Private, Network Discovery, and File/Print on all computers ?

Comment: There might be some security setting in the router for the 5 GHz network. First thing, check the router. (Your rent about Windows 11 is not in place, regardless if it's valid and true. This is a Q&A site.)

Comment: I removed the unrelated comment about File Explorer since it has absolutely nothing to do with the behavior you describe.

Comment: Do you have wireless isolation enabled on the 5GHz?